# Awt Dimension class vs custom Pair class performance

Tags: java, awt, coordinates, dimension

Awt's [Dimension class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) can do a lot of things, converting between different numeric types and etc. I'm using these classes to represent cells on big 2d worlds that need to be updated per ms. Can I get a performance hit, if I stick with the Dimension class all along instead of using my custom Pair  class? This is my custom Pair class:

```
public class Pair<A, B> {
private A first;
private B second;

public Pair(A first, B second) {
    super();
    this.first = first;
    this.second = second;
}
public static <A, B> Pair <A, B> createPair(A first, B second) {
    return new Pair<A, B>(first, second);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hashFirst = first != null ? first.hashCode() : 0;
    int hashSecond = second != null ? second.hashCode() : 0;

    return (hashFirst + hashSecond) * hashSecond + hashFirst;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other instanceof Pair) {
        Pair otherPair = (Pair) other;
        return 
        ((  this.first == otherPair.first ||
            ( this.first != null && otherPair.first != null &&
              this.first.equals(otherPair.first))) &&
         (  this.second == otherPair.second ||
            ( this.second != null && otherPair.second != null &&
              this.second.equals(otherPair.second))) );
    }

    return false;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{ 
       return "(" + first + ", " + second + ")"; 
}

public A getX() {
    return first;
}

public B getY() {
    return second;
}
}
```

When I was looking for Pair implementations I haven't seen the mention of Dimension anywhere, wonder why..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I was looking for Pair implementations I haven't seen the mention of Dimension anywhere, wonder why..

Well, a `Dimension` could be seen as a `Pair` but not the other way round. A dimension has two int values while a generic pair can have any combination of types.

Btw a generic pair doesn't provide much more info on the data than that there are two objects in some relation. That's why generally using specialized classes is preferred over pairs, e.g. `Dimension` defines the two values as width and height and nothing else, so you gain additional information over just using `Pair<Integer, Integer>`.

Besides that, you'd need to note that `Dimension` has integer fields and thus can only represent integer extents, i.e. width = 2.5 is not possible. Besides that I'd not use `Dimension` for representing positions since although the data seems similar the semantics (meaning) of that data is not (dimension defines an area while positions are points).

You might consider using [`Point2D.Float`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Float.html) or [`Point2D.Double`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) instead.

Comment: The representation of the cells is a 2d array, I only need to work with integers, does the Dimension win then?

Comment: Although I see my ignorance, who do I define Pair generic if I want to use it only with integers? I now realize I shouldn't have, if I make it specific to Integers, performance-wise it will be the same as Dimension then, right?

Comment: @RyanMarv yes from a performance point of view there shouldn't be any difference. If you need integer positions only consider using `java.awt.Point` or using a more expressive name than "Pair" :)